# Fail to use a "Topic" in ActiveMQ Artemis with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

I had created an MULTICAST address as below:

[image]

But when I send a message, Artemis creates a UNICAST queue having the same name with my address:

[image]

In addition, (because it's a ANYCAST) only one customer can read the message.

NOTE. I'd tried to create a MULTICAST queue within the same address. I can send a message from the console. But in my Spring Boot application I wasn't able to send for it any message. And also, my @JMSListener cannot be a customer for this queue.

**EDITED**

I'm using Artemis 2.28.0 and application.properties contains :

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=admin
spring.artemis.embedded.topics=topic1
```

My listener contains :

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${spring.artemis.embedded.topics}")
public void messageListener(String message){
   Facture f = objectMapper.readValue(message, Facture.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide details about your application code and configuration? Also, what version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: to @JustinBertram. I'd edited my question

Comment: Are you setting pubSub=true when you send the message?